# Cloud Computing lock-ins

Tags: cloud

For quite some time I have been thinking to migrate my develoment services v to aws or Google cloud. My fear of doing this is that if I choose a single provider then I feel like I'm locking myself into their cloud.  For example, Google and aws have tools the help us a developers to speed along the development process.  If I choose to work with a tool provided by aws while I'm developing on them then it seems like I'm locking myself into their technology.  If for whatever reason tomorrow we decide to change providers I feel like we are going to be stuck.

Is love to get some feedback on this if possible.

Thank you.

Comment: While this is an interesting question, it's not really on topic here. The answer, by the way, is really complex and has to do with how far you're willing to go for platform independence, and whether you want to still benefit fully from cloud services while remaining independent, how mature your organisation is, how capable it and you are, whether you're trained in modern infrastructure, etc. I've done this analysis for banks, and decided that Docker EE is the way to go, but it has some strong competitors if your needs fit so ymmv.

Answer (score 0):

This largely depends on what kind of move to the cloud you're talking about.

If you think of the cloud as just an abstracted data center and treat it that way, you're only changing *where* you compute.  In that case, just as with moving your compute from one data center to another, you'll be just as locked in to the second data center as you were at the first.  You can move, but it will cost you in effort and time.

If you're talking about going cloud naive, changing *how* you compute, then you'll be fine regardless of what public cloud you choose.  Containerization, serverless functionality, Infrastructure as Code, all of these things are different from cloud to cloud, but also the same.  If you learn one, it is just "a hop, skip, and a jump" from another and migrating between clouds is not rocket-surgery with a little practice (which is free in all three main public clouds).

So it's hard to say without knowing more about what you're going to be doing in the cloud.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is still a very valid and good question, but sadly with no easy or quick answers for the whole of it. Let me just give my 2 cents and maybe some additional reading which might help you find out where you want to go.

In my experience, it just does not happen that you change your cloud provider very often as you do not need to do it usually. The big ones all have very good offerings on which you can build everything you imagine possibly. All of them with different strengths and weaknesses, which you have to educate yourself about or find someone to help you do that when making a decision. But end of the day the exact cloud provider often does not make as much of a difference as actually changing your way of working, your culture and your processes to be "cloud native" which is just a fun way of saying, that you want to automate just about everything you can.

The reason to go to the cloud is not some tool, but the possibility to automate away all the boring and annoying stuff, so you can concentrate on your actual product. There is many ways to do that and many levels on how far you can or want to go, but that is precisely the part which you need to find out for your company. Getting some help along the way is a great idea here.

I found following article a good read on this topic: https://bravenewgeek.com/multi-cloud-is-a-trap/

If you really must go for multi cloud, you could check out the whole "hyperconverged infrastructure" topic (hyper hyper! (c) scooter). I myself do not buy into that, as putting abstractions over abstractions never really worked out so well :)

I hope it helps at least a little bit.